unmarshal values into struct golang
I have this struct:
type Movies struct {
   ID string
   Title string
   Actors []struct {
      Name string
      City string
      State string
      Country string
   }
}

And then I have my sql query and logic:
query := `select m.id as id, m.title as title, m.actors as actors from Movies where id = $1`

rows, err := db.Query(query, movieID)

var rowsOut []types.Movies

    for rows.Next() {
        var movies types.Movies
        var actors_json string

        scanerr := rows.Scan(
            &movies.id,
            &movies.title,
            &movies.actors_json
        )
    }

So when I print out fmt.Println(actors_json), it prints out the way I want it to, actually exactly the way its stored in the db which is like:
{"actors": [{"name": "x", "city": "Miami", "state": "FL", "country": "US"}]}

but then when I go onto unmarshal it and add it to the struct:
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(actors_json), &movies)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error unmarshaling JSON:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Unmarshalled TSD:", movies.Actors)
    }

        if scanerr != nil {
            return rowsOut, err
        }

this fmt.Println("Unmarshalled TSD:", movies.Actors) prints [], like its empty?
Why would this happen? Could someone please explain? I've been stuck for some time now, so thank you in advance.

What type is movies? If it's a slice, this won't work. You could unmarshal into &movies[0] for the actors of the first movie in the slice, etc.

Hey @Zyl . So movies is defined as var movies types.Movies .

Please show all the code. There's clearly something missing between the code scanning the values and the code printing the unmarshalled struct.

https://go.dev/play/p/rYX7o38DSfm can you reproduce the problem?

You need to add JSON tags:
type Movies struct {
    ID     string `json:"id"`
    Title  string `json:"title"`
    Actors []struct {
        Name    string `json:"name"`
        City    string `json:"city"`
        State   string `json:"state"`
        Country string `json:"country"`
    } `json:"actors"`
}

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(actors_json), &movies.Actors); err != nil {
 return err
}

links:
https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-struct-tags-in-go
